# Android Unit test with Volley

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-volley, android-instrumentation

Is it possible to write a unit test for my android application where I use Volley for network request. For Eg. I want to write a unit test for a log in feature where in I post a volley request with users credentials and check for a valid user Object in the response. Has anyone done anything similar? Kindly provide examples or references.

This is my login method:

```
    public void login() {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();
        String emailString = email.getText().toString();
        jsonRequest.put("email", emailString);
        String passwordString = password.getText().toString();
        jsonRequest.put("password", passwordString);

        NetworkUtil.postLogin(new Listener<User>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(User response) {
                setUser(response);
                onUserSuccess();
            }
        }, new ErrorListener("postLogin") {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                super.onErrorResponse(error);
                onUserError(error);
            }

        }, jsonRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

And my postLogin method would be something like adding a volley request:

```
    public static void postLogin(Listener<User> listener, ErrorListener errorListener,
        JSONObject jsonRequest) {
    VolleySingleton
            .getInstance()
            .getRequestQueue()
            .add(new GsonRequest<User>(getUrl("login"), "user_profile", User.class, jsonRequest, Method.POST,
                    listener, errorListener));
}
```

Comment: please do support your question with some piece of code or result of your research. see [ask]

Comment: Now how can I add a unit test to test this functionality where in I can check if the user object I get in my onResponse is a valid object with the correct credentials.

Comment: Aside: if your code under test is dependent on another (real) service, then it's not a unit test.  Integration has become a factor in that test.

Comment: Ok So can I write an integration test with Android instrumentation test framework? If yes then please give an example. If no what other frameworks can I use to resolve this.

Answer (score 7):

Suggest you using `CountDownLatch` to await the volley response so that you can do the test. Otherwise your test will end before the response.

In your unit test class using:

```
final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);

/** your code here wait for response**/

signal.await();

/** your code here**/
```

In the on response method you should add 
`signal.countDown();`

here is the reference link https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/173