# Unit Testing In Network With Using Volley in Android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, android-volley

I am trying to test functions from my Presenter Class. In below, I can reach `getSomeThing()` function however, I cannot reach the `getData()` and `getError()` functions.

Volley functions are not working in unit tests. Further help would be highly appreciated as I am struggling with this for over a week.

Below is my Presenter Class, Presenter Listener and Test Function.

my Presenter Class:

```
public abstract class SomePresenter implements BasePresenterListener {

    private static final String sTAG = SomePresenter.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context context;
    private Integer testInteger;

    protected SomePresenter(Context context, Integer testInteger) {
        this.context = context;
        this.testInteger = testInteger;
        onResponse();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            getSomeThing();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final GetRequest<SomeResponse> someResponseRequest =
                ApiRequests.getSomeResponse(
                        new Response.Listener<SomeResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(SomeResponse response) {
                                getData(response);
                            }
                        }
                        ,
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
                                errorResponse.setMessage(Constant.NETWORK_ERROR);
                                getError(errorResponse);
                            }
                        }
                );

        NetworkInstance.addRequest(context, poiResponseGetRequest, sTAG);
    }

    public static void cancelRequest(Context context) {
        NetworkInstance.cancelAllRequests(context, sTAG);
    }

    protected abstract void getSomeThing();

    protected abstract void getData(SomeResponse response);

    protected abstract void getError(ErrorResponse response);
}
```

my BasePresenter Class:

```
public interface BasePresenterListener {
    void onResponse();
}
```

my Unit Test Function:

```
    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        new SomePresenter(mockContext, 107){

            @Override
            protected void getData(PoiResponse response) {
                SomeLogger.debug("getData works");//this is not called.
            }

            @Override
            protected void getSomeThing() {
                SomeLogger.debug("getSomeThing works!");//this is called.
            }

            @Override
            protected void getError(ErrorResponse response) {
                SomeLogger.debug("ErrorResponse works!"); //this is not called.
            }
        };
    }
```

I have looked below links none of them solved my problem.

[Unit testing a network response. Works when debugging, not when actually running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032558/unit-testing-a-network-response-works-when-debugging-not-when-actually-running)

[Android Unit test with Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399423/android-unit-test-with-volley)

In my case is I can reach the `getSomething()` function from unit test  but I cannot reach the `getData()` nor `getError()` functions because Volley does not seem to work in unit tests.

All, `getSomething()`, `getData()`, `getError()` functions are callback functions, I can reach the `getSomeThing()` function but I cannot reach the `getData()` and `getError()` functions.